# How to export path to flutter-bin on Mac?

Tags: flutter, macos, path, export

I have a Mac book with Apple Silicon, and I've downloaded the Flutter SDK and unzipped to $HOME/development folder.
After it, I've created the file .zshrc in $HOME folder using Nano text editor with the following command:
nano $HOME/.zshrc
Then, I've added the following line in order to export flutter/bin path:

export PATH="PATH:$HOME/development/flutter/bin"

When I saved the .zshrc file and refreshed the changes using:

source $HOME/.zshrc

when I try for example flutter doctor, I am getting the following message:

"env bash no such file or directory".

Wher I did make a misstake?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$` sign before `PATH`. It should be like this:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Documents/flutter/bin`.

The complete declaration for `flutter`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Documents/flutter/bin
```

Comment: I need Flutter with XCode, I don't installed Andorid SDK on Mac. Also, when I export flutter path, I cannot run the following zsh commands, such mkdir, rm, cp, rmdir etc until I delete .zshrc. Why?

Comment: Ok, that is optionally. `XCode` doesn't need any thing else.  The `zsh` commands are not related to exporting flutter path. Note that, after any changes in `.zshrc` you have to quit terminal and reopen it.

Comment: Thank you, now it works fine. Best regards.